# advanced profiling build error

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to enable the **"Advanced profiling"** in the new `Android Studio 2.4 preview 2`, but I'm getting build error in message log:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithProfilers-transformForRelease'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.47 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I'm trying to do this on an existing project. When I try on a new project it works without a problem. Does anyone have any idea what the error says or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Android Studio 3.0 fixed this problem with the profiling tools revamped. My suggestion is to update your AS.